# Mercurial - `hg graft` with custom destination?

Tags: mercurial, rebase, cherry-pick

Is there a way to graft a commit onto somewhere *other* than the current revision?

The documentation makes it sound like there isn't:

> hg graft [OPTION]... [-r REV]... REV...
>
> copy commits from a different location

And I don't see any parameters that can be passed to `hg graft` to do so. I'm surprised though that `hg rebase` allows this with the `-d` flag, but `hg graft` doesn't. Just like how sometimes I want to rebase a branch to somewhere other than the current revision, sometimes I want to graft a branch to somewhere other than the current revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the rebase extension to achieve this. Do `hg rebase -r <rev> -d <dest> --keep` to rebase the  onto  while keeping the old rev.

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. One bummer is apparently bookmarks will still be moved during the rebase, but that can be fixed pretty quickly.

Comment: @Mark I no longer understand your question, which seemed to state you wanted something other than rebase and that you already knew rebase could do this.

Comment: @DaveInCaz no, I didn't realize rebase could do this until your answer. After I read your answer I checked out the man page for rebase and found out about the bookmarks.

Comment: @Mark got it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally the answer is "no", but you can still get the desired effect.

The help text for `graft` says "copy changes from other branches onto the current branch
" which implies that if you first update to the destination changeset, you can get the result you want.

Presumably you want to use graft to make an actual copy, vs rebase which would "move" the changeset. So this will get that result although it requires several steps.

To summarize:

```
hg up <destination revision>
hg graft <source revision>
hg up tip
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed this would achieve the desired ultimate effect. However I'm really interested in a solution that won't make me `hg up` anywhere. This is for cases where my current checkout is far from the destination and I would waste time updating to it (and potentially back, if I just want to stay where I am).

Comment: @Mark yeah those kinds of updates can take a while, that's for sure!